# Transforming sentence to passive

Tags: passive-voice, active-vs-passive

I am trying to **transform this sentence into passive form**:

*They are thought ... in a deserted cottage. [hide]*

My guess is:

*In a desert cottage they are thought to be hidden.*

Is that correct?

Comment: This is a particularly idiotic question, since _They are thought_ is already passive. But ignoring that, your answer is right, but muich less natural than if you left the order of the sentence unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I think no question is idiotic, especially when it comes to learning, but I was wondering if the question made sense as well...It belongs to an exercise book just in case. Anyway, thanks for confirming, if you put it as an answer I'll happily mark as your solution as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already in the passive voice, but I think the intention is

> A desert cottage is thought to be the place where they are hidden.